# plotting only the most common levels of a variable in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

In my dataset I have a column "chemotherapy", which has over 800 different levels. I want to plot the most common, say, 10 types of chemo patients had each year.

What I don't know is how to make geom_bar display only the levels of selected frequencies.

This can be represented in the `diamonds` dataset, where I would like to display only the 3 most common levels of `cut`.

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("forcats")

diamonds %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_infreq(factor(cut)))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))*100 ))
```

The graph shows the frequencies of each level, but say I want to only display the top 3?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, summarizing and filtering the data frame before running the `ggplot` call and using `geom_col`:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  count(sort = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = pct)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Problem is that if I do it your way, I don't know how to add additional aesthetics to the plot, because the data has been altered.

In my data, I want to use facet_wrap(~year), but your method would not allow me to do so. To use the `diamonds` as an example, how do I add `aes(fill = color)` to the graph you made?

Comment: If you want to add year information to the plot, you would need to change the dplyr code that filters `diamonds`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that @alanocallaghan?

Comment: Everything up to `ggplot` in this example is `dplyr` code used to summarise `diamonds`. If you want to include year information, you would have to include it at (eg) the grouping stage.

Comment: See my answer for an example. It's probably not what you want to accomplish but the idea should help.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of cardinal40's answer to add information about color.

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("forcats")

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  count(sort = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = pct, fill = color)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this way I am unable to plot only the top 3 factors of cut, which is my other requirement. seems like the two methods are mutually exclusive?

Comment: No, you just need to change the code to filter the data the way you want to. Have you tried altering the dplyr code?

Comment: `diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% count(sort = TRUE) %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(color) %>% slice(1:3) %>% ungroup() %>%mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = pct, fill = color)) + geom_col()`